# How to fetch data from xml look like string?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a xml like string as below

```
<Link id="xyz" href="http://psi.gov.ie">Data</Link> <Pr name="Providor Name"/>
```

And I need a provider name that is name attribute of Pr tag.
I tried this to get xml.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
info_xml = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(str))
```

But it can't do as this isn't valid xml as it does not contain root element.
So, What is the best way to get this thing? Any string manipulation will also do.

Comment: I would go for `Beautifulsoup`. Could you post some xml sample?

Comment: @Slslam Can't go for it. As there are some dependency issues with it. I can use elementtree or string manipulation only.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap a tag around the string

```
info_xml = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring('<root>' + str + '</root>'))
```